# Amazon EC2 EBS CentOS 6.5 Storage Capacity not Added to Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

I have created a custom CentOS 6.5 image and registered it to AWS as EBS root device type. When I launch an instance, it works perfectly well, except that the storage capacity (instance storage to be included according to the instance type) is not added to the instance.

I made a try booting an instance using the official CentOS 6.5 AMI that is located in the AWS Marketplace, but I got the same result.

Does anyone know the reason, if it is a known issue, or whatever?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that the instance store is attached at launch time. From the AWS console it should look something like this:

[image: Attaching Instance store]

Once you boot the instance you have to create a filesystem in the drive by running:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
```

Then you need to mount that drive somewhere in your root filesystem:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/myinstancestore
mount /dev/sdb /mnt/myinstancestore
```

You can run these commands to check that your drive is mounted:

```
df -h
mount
```

You can also add the mount entry to your `/etc/fstab` file so that it mounts permanently after every reboot:

```
/dev/sdb /mnt/myinstancestore ext4 defaults 1 2
```

Comment: Adding a link to the relevant documentation of AWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#Using_AddingDefaultLocalInstanceStorageToAMI